# radio button ripple effect coming initially on page load

Tags: html, css, animation, ripple

I have added ripple effects to the radio buttons on my code .it is working fine on click of radio button but ripple effects are coming initially on page load , i have taken the reference from below example

https://codepen.io/lorenzodianni/pen/ByXMYB/ , can any one please help me regarding this , thanks in advance

```
 <div _ngcontent-c4="" class="col-md-3 text-right po-list-radio">
        <div _ngcontent-c4="" class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
            <input _ngcontent-c4="" checked="checked" class="custom-control-input" id="valid" name="inlineRadio" type="radio">
            <label _ngcontent-c4="" class="custom-control-label label-font mt-1" for="valid">Valid</label>
        </div>
        <div _ngcontent-c4="" class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
            <input _ngcontent-c4="" class="custom-control-input" id="expired" name="inlineRadio" type="radio">
            <label _ngcontent-c4="" class="custom-control-label label-font mt-1" for="expired">Expired</label>
        </div>
        <div _ngcontent-c4="" class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
            <input _ngcontent-c4="" class="custom-control-input" id="all" name="inlineRadio" type="radio">
            <label _ngcontent-c4="" class="custom-control-label label-font mt-1" for="all">All</label>
        </div>
    </div>

@-moz-keyframes ripple {
  5%, 100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes ripple {
  5%, 100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes ripple {
  5%, 100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
* {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}



input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

input[type="radio"] + label {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
input[type="radio"] + label:before, input[type="radio"] + label:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
input[type="radio"] + label:before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  background: #1565C0;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 18px #E0E0E0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 18px #E0E0E0;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 18px #E0E0E0;
}
input[type="radio"] + label:after {
  top: 49%;
  left: 9px;
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  opacity: 0;
  background: #3f51b5;
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
}
.custom-radio .custom-control-input:checked~.custom-control-label::after
{
  background-image: none;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label:before {
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4px #E0E0E0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4px #E0E0E0;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4px #E0E0E0;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label:after {
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  -moz-animation: ripple 1s none;
  -webkit-animation: ripple 1s none;
  animation: ripple 1s none;
}
/* fixes initial animation run, without user input, on page load.
*/
 .custom-radio label:after {
  visibility: hidden;
 }

 .custom-radio input:focus + label:after {
  visibility: visible;
  }
```

Comment: if you do not see effect when page lode then you have to remove `checked` key word from `<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio-category" checked/>` code of line.

Comment: thanks for your reply ...  i want to hide ripple effect on page load , is it possible to hide even if radio button is checked true ????

Comment: no sir this is impossible because ripple css for when checked the radio button then we can see effect. we can not remove ripple effect when screen is load and radio button is checked.